# LSTM with batch size = 1 and variable timestep error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Hello everyone i'm trying to train my LSTM model with batch_size = 1.
The input is a list of 2d arrays each containing variable timestep since each audio has different length and a fixed number of feature, so each element of the list looks like this (Tx,Number_of feature). For example (random):

```
X=[]
for i in range(0,420):
   X.append(np.random.rand(np.random.randint(1,10),12))

y = np.random.rand(420)
y = to_categorical(Y,num_classes=5)
```

I've tried to pass the inputs as follows:

```
def rnn(X,y):

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None, X[0].shape[1])))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=3,batch_size=1,validation_split=0.3)
```

However i got the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\mp95\PycharmProjects\Thesis\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 573, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (86, 12)
```

I thought i had to reshape each element of the list as follows (1,Tx,number_of_features), so i did that:

```
def rnn(X,y):
for s,x in enumerate(X):
    seq_len = x.shape[0]
    X[s]=np.reshape(X[s],(1,seq_len,x.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None, X[0].shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=3,batch_size=1,validation_split=0.3)
```

But again i can't seem to make it work:

```
File "C:\Users\mp95\PycharmProjects\Thesis\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 744, in check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 420 target samples.
```

how can i feed samples with variable timesteps? i found some similar questions but can't really get it to work.

EDIT: Added random parameters initialization for minimal reproducibility as pointed out in the comments

Comment: what is the shape of `y`?

Comment: @learner shape of y is (420,5), X is when passing it a list of 420 elements, each element is an array of (timesteps,12).

Comment: `X` is (420, timesteps, 12) and `y` is (420, 5)?

Comment: @learner yes correct. But being X a list (since i can't use a 3D matrix becouse timestep is variable) it does not have a shape...but yes (420,timesteps,12). Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Please include a _complete_, but minimal, code example that can be run and leads to this error. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you @MathiasMüller added random parameters initialization

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the input shape in the **LSTM** layer should be `(x.shape[0],x.shape[1])` in your case.please check .for more details use [enter link description here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)

Comment: If you have variable length data it is possible to leave the timestep as None, this allows for Online SGD in LSTM

Answer (score 0):

You should use `train_on_batch` instead of `fit`.

`fit` will try to create a numpy array with consistent dimension, which will be a problem in your case.

You can write your own custom `fit` with `train_on_bacth`, `predict_on_batch`, and `test_on_batch`.

```
def train_task(simple_conv, X, y_ohe, EPOCH, train_split=1.0):
    # single zero padding for NULL datas


    report_acc = 0.0
    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        print(f'Training epoch {epoch} ...')
        avg_loss = 0.0
        avg_acc = 0.0
        avg_mae = 0.0

        for sample_i in tqdm(range(int(len(X)*train_split))):
            [train_loss, acc, mae]   =  simple_conv.train_on_batch(X[sample_i].reshape(1,X[sample_i].shape[0], X[sample_i].shape[1]), 
 , 
                                        y_ohe[sample_i].reshape(1,5))
            avg_loss += train_loss/(len(X)*train_split)
            avg_acc += acc/(len(X)*train_split)
            avg_mae += mae/(len(X)*train_split)
        report_acc = avg_acc
        print(f'f1: {avg_acc} mae: {avg_mae} loss: {avg_loss}')
        #print('Running validation ...')
        avg_loss = 0.0
        avg_acc = 0.0
        avg_mae = 0.0

    return simple_conv, report_acc
```

Here's a repo doing something similar (also includes a paper): https://github.com/zabir-nabil/activity-recognition-abc

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying to use `train_on_batch` right now but i have a couple of thoughts/questions. unlike in `fit` i have to manually shuffle training data for each epoch iteration right? Also `train_on_batch` seems to return just `[train_loss,acc]`, the code might be outdated? I tried to find an example in your repo but without succes.